# Application that can aggregate all my French bank accounts (i.e., Mint for French bank accounts)

Tags: finance

I'm looking for a program or web application that can aggregate all of my French bank accounts. For my American bank accounts I use Mint, however Mint doesn't work for French bank accounts.

Any operating system, browser, price or license  is fine.

Comment: Any idea why mint doesn't work for your french accounts? Is it lack of or incompatible API or just as simple as the french accounts using comma as a decimal separator?

Comment: @SteveBarnes I guess each bank has its own API

Comment: That tends to be the problem, also each probably has it's own authorisation process and so forth that provide a set of hoops that any developer has to jump through for each bank. Of course unless there is a regulatory driver banks rarely see any advantage in making it easier for people to also use other banks, _(they prefer to keep all of your business to themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to take a look at [Bankin'](https://bankin.com/en/home.html) which is a french start-up independent of the banks that provides a mobile App, (Android & iPhone), which provides at least reporting across [dozens of french banks](https://support-en.bankin.com/article/171-available-banks) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170828030943/https://support-en.bankin.com/article/171-available-banks)), (and many UK, German & Spanish banks).

- There are free and charged subscriptions for the service.
- You can only, currently, authorise transactions from within it for a very limited sub-set of banks.
- Amounts are displayed french style even on the UK accounts, *(personally I think £1 234,56 looks strange)*.
- There are some internationalisation issues that can be seen [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bankeen&hl=en) such as Checking Account *vs Current Account* & Fooding *rather than Dining or Eating Out* that will either cause a smile or annoy *I am sure that the [french language edition](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bankeen&hl=fr) is better.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linxo](https://www.linxo.com/):

- free
- supported devices: Android, iOS, Windows Phone, web  browser
- supported banks: BNP, Hello Bank, Caisse d’Epargne, La Banque Postale, Banque Populaire, CIC, Crédit Agricole, Crédit du Nord, Crédit Mutuel, HSBC, LCL, Société Générale

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One can use [Kubera](https://www.kubera.com/):

- non-gratis
- worldwide

  > Kubera thus offers the most reliable connectivity to Banks, Brokerages and nearly any Investment Account from the widest coverage of over 20,000 institutions around the world. [Here's the list.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qe9RN0nNkLAQEv63YapKm-4_WARcCl49dYuOvPUX7y4/edit#gid=2133371046)

Screenshot from https://techcrunch.com/2020/05/25/newton-mail-founder-returns-with-launch-of-personal-net-worth-tracker-kubera/:

[image]